# Types of iterator : Output vs. Input vs. Forward vs. Random Access Iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

How many types of iterators are there in C++ STL? As of now, I know of these:

- Output Iterator
- Input Iterator
- Forward Iterator
- Random Access Iterator

Are there more? What are the differences between them? What are the limitations and characteristics of each? Which type is used when?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you can, find and read "The C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference". This book contains a whole chapter about STL iterators.

Here is a little something from the book:

```
Iterator Category  Ability                          Providers
-----------------  -------------------------------  ----------------------------
Input iterator     Reads forward                    istream
Output iterator    Writes forward                   ostream, inserter
Forward iterator   Reads/writes forward             forward_list,
                                                      unordered_[multi]set,
                                                      unordered_[multi]map
Bidirectional it.  Reads/writes forward/backward    list, [multi]set, [multi]map
Random access it.  Reads/writes with random access  vector, deque string, array
```

Comment: This is out of date now, as it lacks information for C++11, but afaik the only relevant change is that there are now containers that provide forward iterators: `forward_list`, `unordered_set`, `unordered_multiset`, `unordered_map` and `unordered_multimap`.

Comment: @Jules how is this out of date? Since no new iterators are introduced in C++11 and the behavior of the old iterators isn't changed, I'd say it's pretty accurate. Which containers support which iterators is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Maybe it wasn't specifically asked by the question, but the information was included in the answer, so commenting when that information has changed is appropriate.

Comment: "The C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference" 2nd edition includes support for C++11.  Overall, the reference to this book was useful for me as a student of STL.

Comment: We have contiguous iterators in C++17.  We have `contiguous_iterator_tag` in C++20.

Answer (score 18):

The C++ standard also has a Bidirectional Iterator concept, which is a Forward Iterator that can also go backward (with `operator--`). Together, these five form the entire iterator hierarchy in paragraph 24.2 of the C++ standard.

The old STL also had the concept of a [Trivial Iterator](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/trivial.html). See its [Iterator overview](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Iterators.html) for details regarding the various iterators.

Boost designers Abrahams, Siek and Witt have [presented](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/iterator/doc/new-iter-concepts.html) a much more fine-grained set of iterator concepts.

Comment: Downvoted as this answers only the first of the 4 questions posed about these types.  @zkunov's answer is much better, IMO, despite lacking the additional info about old versions / boost.

Comment: @Jules It's unfortunate that this answer got accepted, but downvoting it won't actually rank it lower among the answers.

Comment: @Jules I'm not sure how boost iterators are relevant to the question, since the OP asked about stl / std iterators.

Answer (score 8):

I suspect you know the answer pretty well, but anyway, [these charts](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/) are very helpful in sorting this out