# Difference in behaviour of list<int>::iterator and vector<int>::iterator

Tags: list, c++11, vector, iterator, operators

I have a `std::list<int>` and a `std::vector<int>`. I want to remove *even* elements from them, and duplicate *odd* element in them.

I've two different functions for both of them:

**Vector**:

```
std::vector<int> vec_remove_even_duplicate_odd(std::vector<int> target) {
    std::vector<int>::iterator begin = target.begin();

    while (begin != target.end()) {
        if (*begin % 2 == 0) {
            begin = target.erase(begin);
        } else {
            begin = target.insert(begin, *begin);
            begin += 2;
        }
    }

    return target;
}
```

This works fine. But the same function for `std::list<int>` shows error at the line `begin += 2`:

```
error: no match for ‘operator+=’ (operand types are ‘std::list<int>::iterator {aka std::_List_iterator<int>}’ and ‘int’)
```

If I change it to:

```
begin = begin + 2
```

it shows the following note:

```
note:   mismatched types ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>’ and ‘int’
```

But, if I change that line to:

```
++begin;
++begin;
```

It works fine for `list` too. So what is it with this behaviour, that I might have missed while reading about containers.

Why is the `+=` operator not defined for `std::list<T>::iterator`? And why that message for simple `+` operator? I haven't even created a `reverse_iterator`?

I'm aware that a `vector` is a *contiguous* structure, while a `list` is not. But how will that matter, given that *post-increment* is applicable?
Is this issue specific to `list` only, or some other container also have this issue?

Comment: Since `std::list` is not contiguous, it's iterators can only move one at a time, so `++` works, but `+` doesn't.   See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211914/types-of-iterator-output-vs-input-vs-forward-vs-random-access-iterator and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/BidirectionalIterator/

Comment: @MooingDuck. Thanks. Didn't knew about different kinds of iterators. It's clear now. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `std::list` is actually a linked list, its iterators provide only the functionality that is trivial to implement in such a data structure; in particular, `std::list` iterators are so-called *bidirectional iterators*, not *random access* iterators, thus they do not provide neither `operator+=` nor `operator+`, hence the messages you get.

If in a generic algorithm you *need* to go forward of n elements, regardless of the computational cost of the operation, you can use [`std::advance`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/advance/), which will use `operator+=` for random iterators and repeated application of `++` or `--` in the other cases.

By the way, your loop for `std::vector` doesn't look fine - insertion and removal in a `std::vector` [can invalidate iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules) (including those you are using to iterate over your vector); you should change the approach of your algorithm (maybe the simplest thing is just to copy the elements in a separate `vector`).

Comment: Also, `std::distance` is handy.  And, `std::next` and `std::prev` in C++11 as well.

Comment: Thanks @Matteo. Didn't knew about different kinds of iterators. It's clear now. :)

Comment: Thanks @Matteo for the advice. I've just started learning C++. So, hopefully will learn about the these issues gradually. :)

Comment: @RohitJain: be ready, C++ is an ugly beast :) - by the way, when writing algorithms to work on containers check out the content of [the header `<algorithm>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/), you may well find most of the work already done.

Comment: @MatteoItalia. That is certainly a handful of algorithms in one header. Thanks. Probably will be of use once I learn how to do it myself. :) And yes, it seems like a complex language. Since I've accepted the challenge, let's face it :)

Comment: @MatteoItalia. When I replaced `begin += 2` with `std::next(begin, 2)`, my machine hanged. I had to restart it. Is this the problem with the function or, it hanged just by chance.

Comment: `std::next` doesn't increment the iterator - it returns a new iterator, incremented by the value you specified, which got you stuck into an infinite loop that continued to add elements to the vector. Use `std::advance` (remember: `std::next`=>`+`, `std::advance`=>`+=`). By the way, restarting the machine shouldn't be necessary, you should be able to kill the process before (although on Windows it may require some time once the system start thrashing due to all the requested memory).