# List iterator disfunctionality

Tags: c++, list

I have a small problem:
I am using an iterator to go through a list, but I can't seem to access previous positions using just it.

```
std::list<int>::iterator i;
for(i=mylist.begin();i!=mylist.end();i++)
{
        if(*i<0) fprintf(fout,"%d",*(i-1));//here i want to access the (i-1)th element 
}
```

Comment: Or you could create a new variable after that `if` and save the `i` in that variable, and check with it at the next `if`.
Edit:see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it that works with C++03:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> mylist { 11, -22, -33, 44, -55 };
    std::list<int>::iterator i, j;
    if (!mylist.empty())
    {
        for (i = mylist.begin(); ++i != mylist.end(); )
            if (*i < 0)
                printf("%d ",*--(j=i));
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

With C++11 you can replace the malarky with `j` with [`std::prev(i)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev), as Columbo first suggested....

Notice that I changed your loop to avoid potential attempted access to some imagined element "before" `*begin()`.  You can see it running [here](http://ideone.com/6Cm1BA).

Comment: Without C++11, I'd still use a function instead of that malarkey (but writing it myself or using [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/utility/utility.htm)). As well as less head-scratching to see what it's doing, it would prevent mistakes like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26864387

Comment: @MikeSeymour's function suggestion's good, indeed - it's normally a good idea to implement (or take from `boost` if available) something providing as close to the C++11 interface as possible to make it easy for C++11-literate programmers to follow and reduce later porting effort.  The linked "mistakes" question exhibits typical "undefined behaviour for lack of sequence point" errors that people manage to do with a single iterator anyway - not sure that's particularly relevant).

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`std::prev`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev):

```
fprintf( fout,"%d",*std::prev(i) )
```

Comment: it's telling me prev is no member of std, how do i include it?

Comment: @MihneaGafton It's in the link "Defined in header ... " at the top.

Comment: @MihneaGafton As Nick mentioned its noted in the reference. `<iterator>`.

Answer (score 1):

There are different categories of iterators (see [Types of iterator : Output vs. Input vs. Forward vs. Random Access Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211914/types-of-iterator-output-vs-input-vs-forward-vs-random-access-iterator)). Your code requires a *random access* iterator, whereas `std::list` only provides a *bi-directional* iterator.

One way to work around this is to save the previous value in a variable and use that instead of `*(i-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::list<int>::iterator i;

int temp = mylist.begin(); //temp variable to save the past i

for(i = mylist.begin(); i != mylist.end(); i++)
{
    if(*i<0) fprintf(fout,"%d", temp);//here i want to access the (i-1)th element 
    temp = *i;
}
```

Something like this.