# Iterator disfunctionality

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I have a code in which I basically have positive values and negative values. The negative values represent operators('+'=-1,'-'=-2,'*'=-3,'/'=-4) and I basically have to either divide, to make the sum and so on of the 2 numbers preceding the negative value.

```
std::list<long>::iterator i,j;
for(i=num.begin();++i!=num.end();)
{
            if(*i<0&&num.size()>=2)
            {
                    if(*i==-1)
                    {
                              *i=*--(j=i)+*----(j=i);
                    }
                    else if(*i==-2)
                    {
                              *i=*----(j=i)-*--(j=i);
                    }
                    else if(*i==-3)
                    {
                              *i=*--(j=i)**----(j=i);
                    }
                    else if(*i==-4&&*--(j=i)!=0)
                    {
                              *i=*----(j=i)/(*--(j=i));
                    }//this part is working properly
                    num.erase(--(j=i));
                    num.erase(--(j=i));//here is the only problem
                    break;
    }
}
```

Apparently, I am trying to erase a value from the list that doesn't exist.

Comment: What is this? If your goal is not code obfuscation, rewrite that properly, there is no point spending time trying to debug this.

Comment: `std::prev` may help to replace all those `--(j=i)`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-undefined-behavior

Comment: sorry i have not specified, i hope my edit made it obvious the problem

Comment: @Jarod42 That would improve things slightly.  A better solution would be to avoid mutating the sequence entirely; erasing odd elements in front of the current one is dangerous (if, for example, the current one is the first), and makes the code very difficult to understand.

Comment: @Jarod42 But it would, of course, make the code "correct", even if it remained unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

You have undefined behaviour with:

```
*--(j=i) + *----(j=i);
```

where you modify several times `j` in unspecified order.
using `std::prev` would solve that and would make the code cleaner.

Comment: It's not undefined, since both `j` and `i` are class types, and all of the operators are functions, which introduced sequencing.  On the other hand, the order of evaluation is unspecified, so the compiler could generate the two assignments first, then the three decrementations, then the two dereferences.  Which won't do what he wants.

Answer (score 2):

Stepping aside from the fact that some of your code is undefined behavior and completely unnecessarily cryptic.

```
std::list<long>::iterator i,j;
for(i=num.begin();++i!=num.end();)
{
    // ...
    num.erase(std::prev(i));
    num.erase(std::prev(i));
}
```

We know `num.size()` >= 2, but we don't know that `i` is at least 2 past begin so there are actually two things to erase. It's likely that your first and/or second runs through the loop are trying erase nonexistent iterators.

[edit] Apparently your loop check is `++i != num.end()`. First, don't do that. Second, I guess that effectively means that you're starting one past begin, so that's why you fail on the 2nd erase in the first iteration of the loop:

```
[begin] <--> [item] <--> [item] <--> ...
             ^
             i
```

You're trying to erase the two items in front of `i`. There is only one.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things seriously wrong with your code:

- In expressions like `*--(j = i) + *----(j = i)`, the compiler is free
  to rearrange the operators in just about any way that doesn't violate
  direct dependencies.  So it might do the two assignments first, then the
  three decrementations, and finally the two dereferences (resulting in
  something equivalent to `*(i - 3) + *(i - 3)`).  Or it might do the
  assignment and the two decrements on the right, then the assignment and
  the decrement on the left, and then the two dereferences, resulting in
  the equivalent of `*(i - 1) + *(i - 1)`.  Or any number of other
  combinations.  (If `i` and `j` were pointers, and the operators built-in
  types, you'd have undefined behavior.)  As a general rule: no expression
  should have more than one side effect.  Not only because of order of
  evaluation issues, but because you want people to be able to read your
  code.  (This comment also holds for things like `++i != num.end()`; with
  few exceptions, a condition of a `for`, `while` or `if` shouldn't have
  side effects.)
- Erasing elements of a container when iterating over it should be
  avoided, unless you really know what you are doing.  Depending on the
  type of the container, it might invalidate your iterators; in the case
  of `std::list`, it shouldn't, as long as the element being erased isn't
  the one designated by the iterator, but it's very difficult to
  understand where your iterator ends up.  In your case, you don't seem to
  take any precautions for the case where `i` points to the second
  element; if you try to erase the element in front of it twice, you're
  going to be in trouble.

Finally, it looks to me that you're trying to evaluate an expression in
RPN.  I'll pass on the fact that you're using negative values to
indicate operators—a better solution would be a struct, with a field
for the operator, and a field for the value (ignored in the case of
operators like `'+'`).  Something like:

```
enum Operator
{
    push,
    add,
    sub,
    mult,
    div
};

struct Term
{
    Operator op;
    long value;
};
```

But the classical way of implementing this would be a stack of values:
iterate over the expression without mutating it, pushing values onto
the stack, and popping, doing the operation and pushing the results for
the operators.  If the expression is valid, you'll end up with exactly
one element on the stack: verify this, and that there are at least
enough elements for the operators.

And don't forget that there is such a thing as a switch.  Your loop
should be something like:

```
std::stack<long> stack;
for ( auto current = num.cbegin(), end = num.cend(); current != end; ++ current ) {
    switch ( current->op ) {
    case push:
        stack.push( current->value );
        break;
    //  ...
    }
}
if ( stack.size() != 1 ) {
    //  error...
} else {
    //  results are the only remaining element on the stack.
}
```