# How to generate a specific iterator in c++

Tags: c++, iterator

Is there a way to generate a specific iterator in c++?
In c++, I just find:

```cpp
std::string strHello = "Hello World";
std::string::iterator strIt = strHello.begin();
std::string::iterator strIt2 = std::find(strHello.begin(), strHello.end(), 'W');
```

Where `std::find()` will return a iterator, and `.begin()` is also iterator type. But if I want a iterator initialized will a specific value, like:

```cpp
std::string::iterator strIt3 = strHello[3];  // error
```

How can I do that?

---

Update:
`std::string::iterator strIt3 = strHello.begin() + 3;  // works well`

Comment: [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) iterators are [random access iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) which means that `strHello.begin() + 3` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Some programmer dude Oh, it's true, I don't know why it was invalid when I first tried this. Thanks.

Comment: @HuXixi on the other hand, `std::string::iterator strIt3 = strHello[3];` is completely invalid, because `operator[]` does not return an iterator

Comment: @HuXixi You may have got an error if `const` was used somewhere in your actual code. @robthebloke answer covers this.

Answer (score 7):

You can using [std::next](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) to return the *n*th successor of iterator in a general way:

```
auto it = v.begin();
auto nx = std::next(it, 2);
```

Notice that *n* can be negative number:

```
auto it = v.end();
auto nx = std::next(it, -2);
```

Comment: just curious will this work, auto it1 = it + 2; ? newbie to c++, I am a c programmer moved to C++

Comment: @ Sohil Omer Yes you can, if *it* is a [random access iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator).

Comment: Could you please share any example about the "random access iterator" as string is stream of characters so I can access any index  just like 'C'

Comment: do i need to specify for the random access iterator

Comment: @SohilOmer [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211914/types-of-iterator-output-vs-input-vs-forward-vs-random-access-iterator).

Answer (score 3):

```cpp
void without_const(std::string& strHello)
{
  std::string::iterator strIt3 = strHello.begin() + 3;
}

void with_const(const std::string& strHello)
{
  std::string::const_iterator strIt3 = strHello.begin() + 3;
}

void with_auto(const std::string& strHello)
{
  auto strIt3 = strHello.begin() + 3;
}
```