# What containers are valid to use with std::random_shuffle?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, shuffle, random-access

What containers are valid to use with `std::random_shuffle( RandomIt first, RandomIt last )`?

The [API description](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) says the two iterators need to be random-access iterators -- I guess I'm not clear what a random-access iterator is, and specifically, why `std::vector::begin()` and `::end()` are, but the same from `std::set` and `std::unordered_set` are not.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  std::set<int> s = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
  std::unordered_set<int> u = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
  std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

  std::random_shuffle( s.begin(), s.end() ); // compile error
  std::random_shuffle( u.begin(), u.end() ); // compile error
  std::random_shuffle( v.begin(), v.end() ); // :)

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `std::random_shuffle`. It is deprecated in C++14 and removed in C++17. Use `std::shuffle` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at `set` then down to `iterator` class member it will tell you the iterator type, in this case `BidirectionalIterator`. (The "legacy" bit can be disregarded for this purpose).

For `random_shuffle` it needs to be `RandomAccessIterator`  which means the iterator can be moved in jumps of any integer size (or in other words, the container elements can be accessed in constant time by an integer index).

This is possible for `vector` (offset by an index from the start), but not possible for `set` where the only way to get to the N-th element is to traverse the elements one step at a time (because it's stored as a tree).

More info about iterators: [Types of iterator : Output vs. Input vs. Forward vs. Random Access Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211914/types-of-iterator-output-vs-input-vs-forward-vs-random-access-iterator)

I couldn't find a table in the Standard of containers vs. iterator types, however if you look at [this container property table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) then any container that supports `operator[]` for an integer index is random access, otherwise it isn't.  So that is `<array>`, `<vector>` and `<deque>`.   (The `map`s use operator[] in a different way).  Also there is `<string>` which doesn't appear in that table, plus any user-defined container which offers random access iterators of course.

NB. `set` is a sorted container so it couldn't be random-shuffled anyway.