# STD c++ set using find function

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, tree, set

Let's say I want to find the pointer to the element X in my set.I'll do:

```
set<int>S;
int x;
cin>>x;
//insert elements
set<int>iterator :: it = S.find(x);
```

How do i find element right after x in my set now?For example , if my set is :1 , 2 , 3 and x is 2 , I want to print 3.This doesn't seem to work:

```
cout<<*(it+1);
```

It says no match for operator '+'.Thanks!

Comment: [`upper_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/upper_bound)

Comment: Note `set` is an associative container and they generally don't have random access iterators that allow a + operator. ++ operator, yes, but + implies you can add numbers other than one and jump around in the container. That's meaningless for a lot of containers. A linked list for example, requires you to find +1 before you can find +2. A `set` is [typically a tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) and has a similar difficulty.

Comment: @user4581301 Oh , I've just learned about binary trees and heaps, thanks!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211914/types-of-iterator-output-vs-input-vs-forward-vs-random-access-iterator

Answer (score 2):

instead of this:

```
cout<<*(it+1);
```

This:

```
if (it != S.end()) {
    it++;
    if (it != S.end()) {
        cout << *it;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to range check.

Comment: `it++` modifies the iterator. `cout << *std::next(it)` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Wait , if a set is implemented using trees , how will the ++ method work?They won't be stored in contignuos memory

Comment: @asddsdsadsa `it` is an `std::set<T>::iterator` which is not a pointer. It is a `class` that has `operator++` and other operators so it *looks* and *acts* like a pointer but performs the correct operations under the hood, like traverse a tree.

Comment: Addressed comments and fixed.  Thanks for pointing out the boundary case.